# Inequality with volume in Euclidean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Given an Euclidean Space and vectors $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k, b_1, b_2, \ldots b_n$.

Is it true that $V(a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_k, b_1, b_2, \ldots , b_n) \leq V(a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_k) \cdot V( b_1, b_2, \ldots , b_n)$ ?

EDIT: $V(a_1,a_2,…,a_k,b_1,b_2,…,b_n)$ is volume in k+n dimensional parallelogram, and the other V's are in k and n dimensional parallelogram, respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by $V$?

Comment: Volume of parallelogram span by vectors.

Comment: Do you mean $V(a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_k, b_1, b_2, \ldots , b_n)$ is the "volume" (measure) in $k+n$ dimensional space, and the other $V$'s are in $k$ and $n$ dimensional space, respectively?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

The answer is positive and it follows from [generalized Hadamard inequality for Gram determinant](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gram_determinant). The proof is in Chapter IX, $\S$5 of  "The theory of matrices" by F. R. Gantmacher. There are also translations “Matrix theory”, **1**  (1959) and “The theory of matrices” **1**, (1977) published by Chelsea.